# virtual device of genymotion statred but displaying white screen...?

Tags: android, genymotion

can any one guide me to solve this issue... i have install the free version of genymotion 2.3.1 v along with virtual box. i created virtual device from the listed one....virtual device is started but it show only the white screen. image of the virtual device is attached here.

i have tried the following solution
1)setting of network adapter configuration(network IP address, DHCP server etc) setting but it doesn't solve my problem..thanks in advance.
2)re-install the genymotion[image]

Comment: Your video card has to be OpenGL compatible. I found the [Intel Driver Update utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu) which is a great tool which scans through your computer and recommends updates.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I updated my graphic card driver but no luck :( any help ??

Comment: OpenGL 2 - OpenGL 1 is not enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do the following if you have Intel graphics driver.

Please try to update you graphics card driver to the latest one first from this below link

[Intel Drivers auto update download link updated](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu)

and then please make sure your color setting is 32 bits after updated the driver, and then try to start the virtual device again.

Comment: I've got this issue when I changed my laptop power plan. Then found this post.
The power save plan changes the color mode to 16-bit. Change back to 32-bit as per advice and it works.

Answer (score 4):

**Please check your graphic card you need graphic card to support it**

Comment: in my display adapter i have only Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family..! so should i use external graphics card..?

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 virtual devices: nexus 5, nexus 7, nexus 10.

On nexus 5 there's no problem for running normally but nexus 7 and 10 have "white screen".

My preferences - network :
I make 4 Host-only network VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter#1, #2, #3, #4

.

Setting of Nexus 5:

Network - Tab Adapter 1 : Ethernet Adapter#1

Network Tab Adapter 2 : Ethernet Adapter#2

Display Video Memory : 32MB

.

My solution:

1. Update to newest VirtualBox from 4.2.12 (bundling with my genymotion 2.3.1) to 5.0.14
2. Open VirBox setting - open System and tab "mother board, decrease "Base Memory" from red zone to green zone (My case, I change from 3000MB to 1500MB).
3. Open network - check enable netwok adapter with attach to Host-only adapter.

   3.1 tab Adapter 1 : choose same with Nexus 5 (adapter#1), for nexus 7 n 10

   3.2. tab Adapter 2 : choose different with Nexus 5 (adapter#3 for nexus 7 and adapter#4 for nexus 10)
4. For Display Video Memory, I increase from 32MB to 64MB
5. Finish and I can running my nexus 7 and 10 normally.

Hope my solution will help your problem too ^_^

regard, from Indonesian with love

Comment: Hi danangmr, Even i did the same thing which you instructed .But it's showing the same white,can you please suggest any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check you BIOS for "INTEL VIRTUALIZATION TECH" is enabled. That's a must for VM Box.

Answer (score 0):

On my Lenovo ThinkPad x61t with Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family on Windows 10 Professinal 64-bit I had the same issue (White Screen). The Genymotion Version is 2.8.1 (Revision 20161122-fbfadbe) and the VirtualBox Version (with GuestAdditions installed) is 5.1.12 r112440 (Qt5.6.2).

On the same mashine with xUbuntu 16.04. everything went fine - same Genymotion and VirtualBox versions.

### Solution

The current graphics driver version automatically installed buring the Windows 10 is 8.15.10.2697. In contrast, the lasted version offered by Intel is 8.15.10.1930 (15.12.75.4.1930), which is a lower version number.

Installing the *older* driver version from Intel solved the problem: Now the VM shows a black screen and the toolbar on the right.