# GenyMotion emulator does not go beyond white screen

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

The genymotion emulator starts from  AndroidStudio. It shows its white screen but never goes beyond that. It never comes to the home screen. Tried running the app. does not work. I have tried API 18 emulator. does not work. I have tried changing sdk path, setting android_home. does not work??

Comment: What is your OS? Windows 10 is having issues due to VirtualBox having issues.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I have updated to the latest GenyMotion and Android|Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtual device of genymotion statred but displaying white screen...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164415/virtual-device-of-genymotion-statred-but-displaying-white-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked logs for errors or possible explanation? Do you have both VirtualBox and Genymotion configured properly? It is hard to answer your question more accurately cause you did provide little information.

Answer (score 0):

Going into my BIOS and enabling Intel Virtualization Technology under the CPU Options, and then going into GenyMotion and changing the device's # of virtual processors fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i also faced the same problem ... you can try above all suggestion but what worked for me is :-

- Downloading **Oracle VM VirtualBox**

Here is the link , **DOWNLOAD** and install it.
http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/virtualbox/overview/index.html

Comment: I have installed the Oracle Virtual Box that is bundled with GenyMotion from https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download.

Answer (score 0):

I often have the same problem. If I delete the virtual device and then reinstall it, it usually fixes the problem for me.

- To delete it, open the genymotion desktop application
- Delete the device that's giving you the white screen - select the device and then click on the trash can icon
- After it's deleted, reinstall the device - press add, search for the device, select it and press next twice

The device will be installed again, and it may start properly this time around.