# Getting a white screen when running Genymotion

Tags: java, android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I'm starting Genymotion it gives me a white screen, I used different virtual devices and still the same screen shows up. Tried reinstalling the virtual devices but didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtual device of genymotion statred but displaying white screen...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164415/virtual-device-of-genymotion-statred-but-displaying-white-screen)

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I tried the solutions there but didn't work.

Comment: Check if you have the final version of VirtualBox and if Intel Virtualization is enabled.

Comment: I have the latest version of both the VirtualBox, which is 5.0.4, and Genymotion, which is 2.7.2. How can I check Intel Virtualization is enabled? If you mean entering the Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings > Right click on VirtualBox Host-only network and enable it or checking its properties and checking VirtualBox NDIS6, then yes, I did that. @Arshak92

Comment: @WaleedAdel you can check if virtualization is enabled in your bios. By the way, also check if your Processor supports virtualization.

Comment: How can I do that? @Arshak92

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give to you: use your own device! Develop an android app on a virtual device is really not optimized

Comment: The whole idea of using a virtual device is saving time and if there are any errors or something that needs optimization that's what a virtual device is for.

Comment: You can check error on your own device too, and moreover, you will be able to see the amount of process used by your application or other things like that thanks to developer option in settings.
But it's true that virtual device is usefull when you want to check if your app run on different size of screen.

Comment: It's easier for me to use a virtual device to check quickly if everything is fine. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on using my own device to run the app from Android Studio? What are the steps to do that?

Comment: You just need to put your device on "debug mode", and click on the green button on android studio to run your app. To put your device in debug mode, you have to look in internet how do that because it depends of your devices

Comment: I did that and worked. Thank you. @BenjaminLucidarme

Comment: No problem! You can see the errors on the log box on Android studio.