# Your CPU does not support VT-x

Tags: android, android-emulator, cpu, android-virtual-device, virtualization

I have created AVD, but when I try to run android program, it is showing an
error

> Your CPU does not support VT-x

I enabled virtualization technology in BIOS, but still this error comes up when I try to run my android program.

Comment: share your hardware config details

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 DUO CPU E7300

Answer (score 10):

There are two scenarios:

**Using VMware:** go to "WM" > "Settings" > "Processors" and Activate VT-x as below:

[image]

**Using OS installed on HW:** as others mentioned if your CPU supports that you should activate it in your BIOS.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html), to run an emulator the development system's CPU should support one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

- Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx)
- AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) -- only supported for Linux

Your CPU is [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7300](https://ark.intel.com/products/36463/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7300-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB), which according to the manufacturer **does not** support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). That's the reason for this error.

The workaround is to use an alternative Android Emulator, e.g. [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), as already suggested.

Answer (score 3):

### For Mac users with Apple Silicon (M1/M2/M3)

This error may appear if you select the wrong system image from the list when installing a new emulator. Make sure you make the right choice (see screenshot above)

[image]

Comment: VT-x is Intel's brand-name for the HW virtualization features of their x86 CPUs.  Does Android Studio really show that message on AArch64 M1?  Perhaps if you're running x86-64 Android Studio under Rosetta?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you Just need to follows steps:

First,Go to Control Panel → Program and Feature.
  Then, Click on Turn Window Features on and off. A window opens.
    Then,Uncheck Hyper-V option and restart your system.

Now, you can Start `HAXM` installation.

Check this also https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

**OR**

You can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/account/login/)

Comment: I have also installed genymotion, but when i start genymotion device, it is showing only white screen, nothing else

Comment: Please check your graphic card you need graphic card to support it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164415/virtual-device-of-genymotion-statred-but-displaying-white-screen

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed settings from BIOS, then you just need a restart of your machine.

Comment: I have restarted the machine many times, but still showing error

Comment: Buddy, the CPU you mentioned in the above comments doesn't have support for Vt-x.. See this link.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/36463/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7300-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB

Comment: thanks you so much for your answer. It means i can not run my android program without physical android device?

Comment: You can activate developer options on your android device and enable USB debugging, but you will need a USB android driver for your device to be installed on your machine(I did the same by installing SAMSUNG driver.) and then run your application.. or if you just need to look how your program will look on actual device, build an APK of your program, copy it in your device and install.. if this answer clears your questions then please mark it correct.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have the problem in these days,
you might try the steps described here:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Also according to other answers, you have to be sure that CPU does
support virtualization, and that the virtualziation is on.

Answer (score 1):

There couple of solutions you can try

1. You can Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM.
2. Other solutions can be just to enable Intel Virtualization Technology
   from BIAS.
3. Or you can use an alternative emulator like genymotion to fix this
   problem.

If the above solutions bother you then you can use a physical device for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're
Using VMware**: go to "VM" > "Settings" > "Processors" and Activate VT-x as below:

[image]

Then go to your **Turn Windows feature on or off** and uncheck virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform as below:

[image]

Thank me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of solutions to your problem.

- You can Make an AVD With ARM Instead of HAXM.
- Other solutions can be just to enable Intel Virtualization Technology
  from BIAS.
- Or you can use an alternative emulator like genymotion to fix this problem.
- If the above solutions bother you then you can use a physical device
  for testing purposes.