# Your CPU does not Support VT?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created AVD, it is showing an error that Your CPU does not support VT-x ?

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541801/your-cpu-does-not-support-vt-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in case of AMD CPU's as mine. The only option which is fast and working without any hassle is to use Genymotion and integrate it with Android Studio via plug-in of Genymotion. 
Using this way, you'll have an AVD quickly than messing with other options.

Comment: Or install the ARM emulator images... Genymotion still recommends a x86 chipset